# vertical align of 2 images plus a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align vertically two arrows, one right arrow (`id="freccia-destra"`), one left arrow (`id="freccia-sinistra"`) and a div containing 2 photos (`id="div_galleria"`).

These 3 elements are inside id="div_3";

How can I vertically align them?

Here's is the CSS + Html code:

```css
#div_3{
    
display: inline;
    
}

.r {
    
    display: inherit;
    
}
```

```html
        <div id="div_3" width="100%" height="830" align="center">
            <img class="r" id='freccia_sinistra' src="freccia_sinistra.png" height="100px" onclick="sinistra()">
            <div class="r" id='div_galleria' width="95%" height="800" align="center"></div>
            <img class="r" id='freccia_destra' src="freccia_destra.png" height="100px" onclick="destra()">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div_3{
    
display: inline;
    
}

.r {
    
    display: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="div_3" width="100%" height="830" align="center">
            <img class="r" id='freccia_sinistra' src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/100" height="100px" onclick="sinistra()">
            <div class="r" id='div_galleria' width="95%" height="800" align="center">
                    <img class="r" id='' src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/100" height="200px" onclick="sinistra()">
                    <img class="r" id='' src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/100" height="300px" onclick="sinistra()">
            </div>
            <img class="r" id='freccia_destra' src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/100" height="100px" onclick="destra()">
        </div>
```

use vertical align center if your display is inline or inline-block